# Dynamic Divs in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'm trying to create a page that will be rendered in steps. A user selects a certain option and the next div is dynamically rendered on the jsp page depending on the values selected. for example

**MyPage.jsp**

```
<input type="button" onclick="somejsfunction();" value="Select Choice" />
```

`somejsfunction()` issues a `POST` to the server and sets some values in the session. I then need to render a div in `MyPage.jsp`. I'm thinking i could always just spit out the HTML code from the post call and then append it to the document body in `somejsfunction()` but i was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much cleaner with jQuery

```
function callMe(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/someServlet",
      data: { methodToInvoke: "sayHello" , data: "Abc" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      //msg is the HTML received from server
      $("#someDivId").html(msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering if there was any other way without having to generate the HTML in the post JSP page but im guessing not

Comment: otherway is to just pass data in JSON and you generate fixed HTML with jQuery/javascript putting that data